# Как выполнять консольные утилиты через pipe, используя класс?

Tags: python, linux, ооп, python-3.x, subprocess

**Задача**: С помощью `subprocess` выполнить консольные утилиты, точней, получить скриншот вывода утилиты `top`, используя `imagemagick`.

Сделал так. Имеется `screenshot.py`:

```
class Screenshot:
    file = '/tmp/screenshot.png'
    convert = 'convert -pointsize 20 -font Courier -fill black -background white label:@-'

    def get_shot(self, cmd):
        run_cmd = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(' '), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        subprocess.check_output([self.convert.split(' '), '%s' % self.file], stdin=run_cmd.stdout)
        run_cmd.wait()
        return self.file


def get_top():
    top = Screenshot().get_shot('top -n1 -b')
    return top
```

Из `run.py` исполняю это дело:

```
...
import screenshot 
screenshot.get_top()
...
```

По идее, в случае правильного выполнения `screenshot.get_top()` возвращает  `/tmp/screenshot.png`. Но в процессе выполнения не возвращается ничего. Экспериментальным путем (с помощью `print()` *:)*) я выяснил, что выполнение останавливается на функции`subprocess.check_output()`. Вроде бы аргументы (команды) передаются в функцию верно, в виде списка.

PS. До этого такой же (похожий, без ООП) код успешно работал. Но я решил, что пора бы осваивать ООП и попробовал сделать это, используя класс. Возможно, это глупо, но меня интересует, почему данная функция не срабатывает. В чем прикол?

**UPD**. Для примера. Работающий вариант без классов, где просто вызывается обычная функция:

```
def get_screenshot(cmd):
    file = '/tmp/screenshot.png'
    convert = 'convert -pointsize 20 -font Courier -fill black -background white label:@-'
    try:
        run_cmd = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(' '), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        subprocess.check_output([convert.split(' '), '%s' % file], stdin=run_cmd.stdout)
        run_cmd.wait()
        return file
     except Exception as e:
        return e


get_screenshot('top -n1 -b')
...
```

В данном случае вывод `top` через пайп успешно передается в stdin `convert`, и функция выполняется.

Comment: команда `echo надпись | convert label:@- файл.png` создаёт `файл.png` с надписью `надпись`. она ничего не возвращает в *stdout* (ну, кроме справки в случае неправильных параметров). можно обойтись и без pipe-а: `convert label:надпись файл.png`

Comment: Можно, это я знаю. Хочу python-way.

Comment: от того, что загружает программу не *shell*, а *python*, её поведение вряд ли изменится: она всё равно не будет ничего возвращать в *stdout*.

Comment: То есть, вы не знаете, как исправить проблему с subprocess.pipe? :) Запуск шеллом это легко, я хотел бы разобраться, в чем причина именно моей проблемы.

Comment: если ваш скрипт **действительно** ожидает появления чего-нибудь в *stdout* запущенной программы `convert ...`, то это и есть проблема, так как в *stdout* эта программа **ничего** не выводит (если ей были переданы корректные параметры, конечно).

Comment: Проблема не в том, что convert не возвращает в вывод, а в том, что его не удаётся вызвать с помощью subprocess. Хотя до того, как функция была не в классе, работало. Я постараюсь добавить код, который работал до этого.

Comment: но возможно, что я вас неправильно понял, и ваш скрипт не ждёт ничего из *stdout*, а всего лишь ждёт завершения запущенного процесса. тогда, возможно, проблема в том, что процесс `convert ... label:@- ...` ждёт появления в *stdin* текста надписи, а ему в *stdin* ничего не передаётся. чтобы проверить, передайте надпись прямо с помощью команды `label`.

Comment: Да, возникло недопонимание. Я добавил работающий "безклассовый" пример, где просто вызывается функция. И она работает. Ведь всё просто по логике: 1. вызывается `top...`, 2. передает свой вывод в `subprocess.PIPE`, 3. вызывается `convert` с входным потоком в виде вывода `top...`, т.е. тот же `subprocess.PIPE`. Но если я делаю это через вызов класса, то не работает. Просто я застопорился, потому что этим примером начал учиться применять классы и сразу наткнулся на ошибку, которую не могу осознать.

Comment: Может, что-то с пайпом происходит, либо я подумываю над тем, что в `subprocess` передается список аргументов в виде *двух* списков (`[self.convert.split(' '), '%s' % self.file]`), а не *одного*, хорошо ли это.

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295459/how-do-i-use-subprocess-popen-to-connect-multiple-processes-by-pipes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решилось, как все и предполагали, с помощью вызова шелловского pipe (`...Popen("%s | %s %s" ...`). Хоть это и частичное решение проблемы, но в итоге я принимаю его как решение.

```
class Screenshot:
    file = '/tmp/screenshot.png'
    convert = 'convert -pointsize 20 -font Courier -fill black -background white label:@-'

    def make_shot(self, cmd):
        run_cmd = subprocess.Popen("%s | %s %s" % (cmd, self.convert, self.file), shell=True)
        return self.file


def get_top():
    top = Screenshot().make_shot('top -n1 -b')
    return top
```

Comment: Вы можете что-нибудь вроде `pyscreenshot` использовать вместо внешней команды (или как переносимый интерфейс для этой команды). Для создания pipeline без shell, [можно `plumbum` использовать](https://plumbum.readthedocs.io). Связанный вопрос: [How do I use subprocess.Popen to connect multiple processes by pipes?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/295459/4279)

Comment: @jfs полезный комментарий, спасибо